# JQuery stops working when I use AJAX in my script. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Here is the AJAX part

```
jsonGamesPlayed() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "jsonGamesPlayed.json",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#main_content').append(json.response.games[0].name);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is where this function is called

```
$("#nav3").click(function() {
        $('#main_content').fadeTo("slow", 0.0, function() {
            $('#main_content').empty();
            $('#main_content').append('<?php include("/HTML/about3.html")?>');
            jsonGamesPlayed();
        });
        $('#main_content').fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
    });
```

When I comment out the entire function, the website works fine. But when I try to use it, all of my JQuery/JavaScript stops working. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and Jquery btw, so I have been looking into this problem for a while.

If it means anything, here is the .json file...

```
{
"response": {
    "total_count": 3,
    "games": [
        {
            "appid": 8930,
            "name": "Sid Meier's Civilization V",
            "playtime_2weeks": 629,
            "playtime_forever": 7965,
            "img_icon_url": "fbe80c4743e226f0bf65559c91b12953d4446808",
            "img_logo_url": "2203f62bd1bdc75c286c13534e50f22e3bd5bb58"
        },
        {
            "appid": 221380,
            "name": "Age of Empires II: HD Edition",
            "playtime_2weeks": 47,
            "playtime_forever": 1144,
            "img_icon_url": "109c74df17f9b67ea47d8f01e3d1ec25278b9f73",
            "img_logo_url": "37e9da3f1174891fe38f8fb0206acda8b6bfc729"
        },
        {
            "appid": 113200,
            "name": "The Binding of Isaac",
            "playtime_2weeks": 36,
            "playtime_forever": 38,
            "img_icon_url": "383cf045ca20625db18f68ef5e95169012118b9e",
            "img_logo_url": "d9a7ee7e07dffed1700cb8b3b9482105b88cc5b5"
        }
    ]

}
}
```

And this is the website I got the AJAX tut off of

http://runnable.com/UhY_jE3QH-IlAAAP/how-to-parse-a-json-file-using-jquery

**EDIT:** Ok so I, being new to javascript, forgot to add function in front of my jsonGamesPlayed() function. Thank you @Aditya for the helpful comment. Although everything runs fine now, The data being called from the .json file isnt being appended to the div... Is there something I'm doing wrong with AJAX?

**EDIT 2:** So after some troubleshooting, the AJAX never goes through successfully,

```
function jsonGamesPlayed() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "jsonGamesPlayed.json",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#main_content').html(json.response.games[0].name);
                alert("I am an alert box!");
            }
        });
    }
```

I have placed an alert inside the success function, which never pops up on call. What can possibly be going wrong?

Comment: I noticed you have PHP appended using JavaScript: `$('#main_content').append('<?php include("/HTML/about3.html")?>');` That has too be done on the server. You have to use append with HTML or text only.

Comment: What error are you getting on your browser console?

Comment: Should be `function jsonGamesPlayed() {`

Comment: @RobertDundon, what are you talking about?  When this page is first constructed, the PHP include will presumably place some kind of HTML markup into the jQuery `.append()` method.

Comment: Ajax call is async and so you might need to put those logic you want to call after the jsonGamesPlayed() into success routine.

Comment: you need `dataType: "json"` not `dataType: "text"`

Comment: `dataType: "text",` and your file is a .json...

Comment: @Senthil Can you please explain the asynchronous call from AJAX and how I am suppose to use it properly? Everything is running fine now, but the function isn't appending anything... Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RyanBonomo Asynchronous means, it happens at any time when the page is already loaded, rather than when the page is first "constructed".
Usually, it goes like this:
A website is called and the related php-file starts doing it's think. It's "parsing" -> generating text an html structure.
PHP happens on the server, javascript (and jquery) on your users PC. This is later, so PHP-code like in your append doesn't do anything anymore.
Ajax allows javascript to "call" a php file at any time and get another "parsed" result from the server. This gives you the power to run php even after the first load

Comment: @RyanBonomo Also, regarding further help: Check the server response. To do that, use your inspect tool (rightclick -> Q i firefox, rightclick -> inspect element in chrome), go to network, wait for the page to build a completely, THEN do the ajax-call thing, look for it in the list, click on it and look at the "response" tab. There you can see PHP errors (or even the correctly returned result, if it works fine).
If the answer you see here is the one you've been looking for, you know the error is in your jQuery, if not, it's in your php.

Answer (score 0):

This line right here an issue:

```
$('#main_content').append('<?php include("/HTML/about3.html")?>');
```

You <s>cannot</s> should not `'append'` PHP code within JavaScript functions. PHP is a server-side language that outputs HTML for the browser to parse. JavaScript is a client-side language that interacts with those `'HTML'` or `DOM` elements once the page has already been rendered. You're asking JavaScript to do something it doesn't know how to do.

That being said... you could always `load` your html like so:

```
 $('#main_content').load("/HTML/about3.html", function() {
     // do something
 };
```

or you could AJAX it the traditional way:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/HTML/about3.html",
    type: "POST", // or "GET"
 }).done(function(the_html) {
     $("#main_content").append($(the_html));
 });
```

Comment: This is valid if this is sitting in a PHP page. What could be happening is that the `include()` is throwing an error.

Comment: You can .append() PHP code as used in my code. You can see it on www.lucifest.com (my website). Each page of content is loaded with a seperate .html file (too save code space on index since it's all one file) and I use the php include() function to do that. The comment @Sparky made on my post explains more. But thanks for the .load() advice.

Comment: I guess it is simply appending the result from your html file call. However, definitely not a good practice (JS is the way to go - no need for the PHP unless you need the PHP to actually do something, in which case it would be server-side). Best of luck!